# Change .svn folder for TortoiseSVN 1.7?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I want to rename that folder to have a _ instead . (_svn) by default. I cant find that setting but I know its there somewhere, I did it some time ago on another PC. Any idea where to look?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12114/395718) and [this Subversion release note](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.3.html#_svn-hack) having folders with _svn instead of .svn was just a hack to workaround the inability of some ASP.NET environments to handle folders prefixed with dot. In later ASP.NET environments this problem is fixed, so now there is no need to support the hack anymore. If you're not forced to have _svn folders then just accept .svn, because you don't have control over it. If _svn is a must then use older version of TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states that the option for the setting mentioned above has been hidden since version 1.4.0.

To enable the `SVN_ASP_DOT_NET_HACK` env variable you need to run the installer like this:

```
msiexec /i TortoiseSVN-1.4.0.msi ASPDOTNETHACK=TRUE
```

(Replace version number of .msi accordingly)

Comment: No, its not there on the General tab ... maybe it was removed in version 1.7? Is there another way to set it?

Comment: The documentation indicates that this option is hidden as of version 1.4.0 - however I can't recall to do anything special when installing version 1.6.11 I currently use.